# HTML view of newman json response without collection file

Tags: npm, postman-collection-runner, newman

I have newman generated Json response which i want to use as a input and get back HTML view of it.

I know newman has inbuilt feature of generating HTML file using HTMLExtra when collection file is given. But i don't want to pass collection/environment file instead i will pass newman json response as input.

Comment: You would need to create a new project with some form of templating engine, that would allow you to return the data in the JSON file, as a HTML report.

Comment: Hi @DannyDainton, Can we tweek and re-use newman definded template engine?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve. The reporters will basically be given the same output from Newman, the output from that will be in the form of JSON, CSV, HTML etc based on the one you choose. You can create a custom template for the htmlextra reporter and present the data in any way you want too.